# Android Firebase check connection status?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an App with the Firebase Realtime Database. This app should display a ProgressBar if it isn't connected. How can I do that? I tried it with ".info/connected", but the results seem pretty random. I need to check the connection to the online database, not the offline database. (basically, i want to disable offline capabilities, and show the user if they are offline)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var firebaseRef = new Firebase('http://INSTANCE.firebaseio.com');
firebaseRef.child('.info/connected').on('value', function(connectedSnap) {
  if (connectedSnap.val() === true) 
  {
    /* we're connected! */
  } 
  else {
    /* Give a custom Toast / Alert dialogue and exit the application */
  }
});
```

You can also add this check

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context con) {
        try {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) con
                    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

            if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Then check this in your Activity/Fragment

```
if (isNetworkAvailable)
{
//Do you task
}
else{
/*No internet so  Give a custom Toast / Alert dialogue and exit the application */
}
```

Refer this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities.) for more information

Comment: I tried this before, as I said. But even when I turned off my internet, I still got "true" as a result. That's why I am asking in the first place.

Comment: see my revised answer check for internet and if its not available give proper message and exit your application

Comment: @AhmadBazzi try with `isNetworkAvailable` condition 
Otherwise use this both conditins tougether `if(connectedSnap.val() === true && isNetworkAvailable)`

Comment: in some Android phones it does not work properly. try https://github.com/draxdave/netWatch